# How to pass an id of the item from the list to other function

Tags: javascript

My page displays only names of drivers from my list. I am trying to make it so, when I click on one of them I would get their info displayed below. I am struggling with passing and index from `addLink function` to `driverProfile` , so I can display more details about that specific driver.

Here's the function:

```
drivers2020.forEach(addLink);

function addLink(driver, i) {
  const nameList = document.createElement('a');
  nameList.style.padding="20px";
  nameList.id = `listOfNames${i}`;
  nameList.textContent = driver.name;
  list2020.appendChild(nameList);
  nameList.addEventListener('click', driverProfile(driver));
}


function driverProfile(driver) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const article = document.createElement('article');
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');

  h1.textContent = driver.name;
  span.textContent = driver.age;
  article.textContent = driver.nationality;

  div.appendChild(h1);
  div.appendChild(span);
  div.appendChild(article);

  return div;
}

myProfile = driverProfile(driver);
profile.appendChild(myProfile);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ch8o4z0k/13/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the function inside of an anonymous function by passing `this` to refer that inside the event handler function.

**Change:**

```
nameList.addEventListener('click', driverProfile(driver));
```

**To:**

```
nameList.addEventListener('click', function(){ driverProfile(driver, this) });
```

When appending on clicking you can check if there is any children is exist or not. If exists then remove the element otherwise append the children.

```js
const drivers2020 = [{
    name: "Kimi Raikonnen",
    age: "20",
    nationality: "Finland",
  },
  {
    name: "George Russel",
    age: "30",
    nationality: "UK",
  }
]

drivers2020.forEach(addLink);

function addLink(driver, i) {
  const nameList = document.createElement('a');
  nameList.style.padding="20px";
  nameList.style.width="250px"; //style added to show side by side
  nameList.style.float="left";  //style added to show side by side
  nameList.id = `listOfNames${i}`;
  nameList.textContent = driver.name;
  nameList.maxWidth = '200px';
  list2020.appendChild(nameList);
  nameList.addEventListener('click', function(){driverProfile(driver, this)});
}


function driverProfile(driver, el) {
  var content = el.querySelector('div');
  if(!content){
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const article = document.createElement('article');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');

    h1.textContent = driver.name;
    span.textContent = driver.age;
    article.textContent = driver.nationality;

    div.appendChild(h1);
    div.appendChild(span);
    div.appendChild(article);
    //alert(drhttps://jsfiddle.net/ch8o4z0k/13/#runiver.name)

    el.appendChild(div);
  }
  else{
    content.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center" id="hideH1">Drivers for 2020</h1>
<div id="list2020"></div>
<section id="profile"></section>
```

**Update:** You can wrap the elements inside of a parent element by providing a *class*:

```js
const drivers2020 = [{
    name: "Kimi Raikonnen",
    age: "20",
    nationality: "Finland",
  },
  {
    name: "George Russel",
    age: "30",
    nationality: "UK",
  }
]

drivers2020.forEach(addLink);

function addLink(driver, i) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.classList.add('wrapper');
  wrapper.style.width="250px"; //style added to show side by side
  wrapper.style.float="left";  //style added to show side by side
  const nameList = document.createElement('a');
  nameList.style.padding="20px";
  nameList.id = `listOfNames${i}`;
  nameList.textContent = driver.name;
  nameList.maxWidth = '200px';
  wrapper.appendChild(nameList);
  list2020.appendChild(wrapper);
  nameList.addEventListener('click', function(){driverProfile(driver, this)});
}


function driverProfile(driver, el) {
  var content = el.closest('.wrapper').querySelector('div');
  if(!content){
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const article = document.createElement('article');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    const h1 = document.createElement('h1');

    h1.textContent = driver.name;
    span.textContent = driver.age;
    article.textContent = driver.nationality;

    div.appendChild(h1);
    div.appendChild(span);
    div.appendChild(article);
    //alert(drhttps://jsfiddle.net/ch8o4z0k/13/#runiver.name)

    //el.appendChild(div);
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(div, el.nextSibling);
  }
  else{
    content.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center" id="hideH1">Drivers for 2020</h1>
<div id="list2020"></div>
<section id="profile"></section>
```

Comment: you mean like put the whole function driverProfile inside addLink?

Comment: @Menor, no, I mean only the function call, please check the update in the answer:)

Comment: that doesn't work, you can check it in the jsfiddle

Comment: @Menor, I have updated the answer, please check by running the the executable code snippet:)

Comment: any idea how to make it so it shows only once and when you click it again it hides?

Comment: Works great, thank you. One more thing, is there a way to put the div of the `driverProfile` outside the `nameList tag`? Right now its <a><div></a> , a want so the div would display below the a tag

Comment: @Menor, I have added another solution, please check the second solution in the updated answer:)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. One more question, lets say that there's more drivers in the list, can I make it so it displays 5 in a row then it creates a new row of 5?

Comment: @Menor, yes that's possible, but I will suggest you to try yourself first, if you have you any issue then you can post another question:)

Comment: can you give me a hint, where should I start with that?

Answer (score 3):

You are *executing* `driverProfile` instead of setting it as event listener. You would have to pass a function that calls `driverProfile`, not the result of an immediate `driverProfile` call.

Also, right now your `driverProfile` never does anything with the `div` that it creates. Let's say we want to add it to `profile` for example, like you do with the first profile already:

```js
nameList.addEventListener('click', () => {
  profile.appendChild(driverProfile(driver))
})
```

Comment: Ok it displays the info right now, but it's being  post every time you click on the name one after another, can you limit it just to one?

Comment: Just [remove the old one](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/remove-element/) before adding the new one.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it